# Get datastore entity inside dataflow pipeline step

Tags: java, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm trying to setup a dataflow pipeline that

1. reads entities from datastore,
2. and for each entity found, look up a different entity to extract a property,
3. and use that property value to update the original entity.

How can I look up a specific entity given a Read?  Or is there some better way of doing this?

Here's what I have so far:

```java
static class LookupOtherEntityFn extends DoFn<Entity, Entity> {

    private Entity LookupOtherEntityFn(Entity sourceEntity) {
        final Key someOtherEntityKey = sourceEntity.getPropertiesMap()
                .get("otherEntityKey")
                .getKeyValue();
        final DatastoreV1.Read read = DatastoreIO.v1()
                .read(); // ...... (uses someOtherEntityKey in query)

        // **************************
        // How do I retrieve the entity given a Read?
        // **************************

    }

    @ProcessElement
    public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
        c.output(createBackupEntity(c.element()));
    }

}

Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);

p.apply(DatastoreIO.v1().read()...)
    .apply(ParDo.of(new LookupOtherEntityFn()))
     .apply(ParDo.of(new CreateUpdatedEntityFn())
     .apply(DatastoreIO.v1().write()...);

p.run();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to use the `DatastoreV1.Read` class to read from Cloud Datastore inside a transform. `DatastoreV1.Read` is used specifically as an input transform for an Apache Beam pipeline.

You can use the Cloud Datastore Java client to read an entity inside the implementation of a transform. Ideally, you should implement the transform such that only a single connection is shared across workers and calls are made asynchronously.

Example from API docs:

```java
import com.google.cloud.datastore.Datastore;
import com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreOptions;
import com.google.cloud.datastore.Entity;
import com.google.cloud.datastore.Key;
import com.google.cloud.datastore.KeyFactory;

// Authentication is automatic inside Google Compute Engine
// and Google App Engine.
Datastore datastore = DatastoreOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();
KeyFactory keyFactory = datastore.newKeyFactory().setKind(KIND);
Key key = keyFactory.newKey(keyName);
Entity entity = datastore.get(key);
```

References:
1. https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-java
2. https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-java/0.42.1/index.html
3. https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-java/0.42.1/apidocs/com/google/cloud/datastore/Datastore.html

Comment: If entities were originally written with DatastoreIO.v1(), can they still be read using this Java client code? The Entity classes come from different packages and have much different internal structure.